# Retrieve date's from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

i got a release_date row in my database
now i want too display the latest date on top

my query now:`$sql = "SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY release_date ASC";`

but this ORDER BY just get the first digits (day) of the date
Now i get:

`03-11-2014
12-11-2013
14-07-2011
16-03-2012`

it needs to be:

`03-11-2014
12-11-2013
16-03-2012
14-07-2011`

Comment: Is it stored as datetime?

Comment: Show your table schema i guess `release_date` column type is varchar not date

Comment: That's a string/varchar, and now you're paying the price for not having used a native database type. Convert that field to a NATIVE date/datetime field, which has format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` and then your sorting will "magically" start working.

Comment: The question you should be asking yourself: why are "date" values stored as string datatype in my table, rather than DATE datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to turn your date string into a real date.

```
SELECT * FROM games 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(release_date, '%d-%m-%Y') DESC
```

You can also use this function to refomat your date into the default format and then change the column data type to `date`.

Comment: Oh, don't encourage them

Comment: Anyone else want to place a wager that the followup question (after the table is populated with a suitable boatload of rows) will be: "Why is my query so slow?", or "Why is my query not returning all the rows?"

Answer (score 0):

The solution given by the above answer worked for your situation.

BUT, the best thing to do is to change the column type to datetime, and not by calling functions to cast str to datetime in your query, because you will have to modify all your queries where you use the 'release_date' field.

If you change the data type, you are doing the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use date type for your date field if you have stored it as a string like varchar  you can change the string values to date object while running query but you cannot make use of any index to that by applying some date function what i suggest you to alter your schema and change the type of your date field to as real date below are the steps how you can change it

Step 1 add new column as acopy of your release_date

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN `release_date_copy` DATE NULL AFTER `release_date`;
```

Step 2 save your date string converting it as real date to new column i.e release_date_copy

```
update t
set release_date_copy =  STR_TO_DATE(release_date, '%d-%m-%Y'),
release_date = null;
```

Step 3 change the type of your release_date column to date

```
ALTER  table t CHANGE `release_date` `release_date` DATE NULL;
```

Step 4 copy data from release_date_copy to your real column release_date

```
update t
set release_date =  release_date_copy;
```

Step 5 delete the copy of your column

```
ALTER TABLE t DROP COLUMN `release_date_copy`;
```

Now you can simply query it in descending manner and you can also make use of an index

```
select * from t
order by release_date desc
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d6d48/1)